# Random Number Guesser using Django-Python

Tags: python, django

I want to Implement a Number Guessing Game using Django. However, I am facing issues since with every guess it gets reloaded and therefore the number changes. Any Suggestions?

```
def RanNum(request):
number = random.randint(1,20)
print('Ans:',number)
if request.method=="POST":
    guess=request.POST['Guess']
    num_guesses = 0

    guessed_number= False
    while not guessed_number:
        if not is_valid_num(guess):
            messages.info(request,"A number between 1 and 20 ony (Not Counted):")
            return redirect('/game')

            continue
        else:
            num_guesses +=1
            guess = int(guess)


        if guess < number:
            messages.info(request,"Too LOW.Guess again:")
            return redirect('/game')


        elif guess > number:
            messages.info(request,"Too HIGH.Guess again:")
            return redirect('/game')


        else:
            messages.info(request,"No of Guesses:")
            messages.info(request,num_guesses)
            return redirect('/game')


            guessed_number = True
    messages.info(request,"thanks for playing")
    return render(request,template_name='html/RandomNumApp/Ran.html',)

else:
    return render(request,template_name='html/RandomNumApp/Ran.html',)
```

Comment: Which behaviour do you anticipate and what is not happening as you want?

Comment: You need to separate the random number generator from the guessing view. This way when the user enters the url for the guess, the random number doesn't change.

Comment: Fair Enough! However, if I have to call the number then I may have to use a function right? Won't the calling of the function will be repeated?

Comment: I was also having same problem. I used Start button and connected to views using if statement. If you click start button in HTML page the 'Post' pass a name of button and checks for condition in views.py and generates a random number.[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGNCJ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGNCJ.png) [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoVXR.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoVXR.png)

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code. It is a little short but works perfectly fine!

```
from random import randint
guesses = 0
n = randint(1, 20)
guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 20: "))
while n != "guess":
  guesses += 1
  if guess < n:
        print ("guess is low")
        guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 20: "))
  elif guess > n:
        print ("guess is high")
        guess = int(input("Enter an integer from 1 to 20: "))
  else:
        print ("You guessed it in", guesses, "guesses!")
        break
```

Comment: by the way, this is python 3.8